# Highlight only selected text using jQuery

Tags: jquery

so I'm trying to highlight user selected text. Essentially the user can drag the mouse (while clicked) to select some random text on the page (anything within`<p>` tags). On mouseup I want to change that text to be highlighted and bold.

The requirements for this are that the text selected and ONLY the text selected gets highlighted. So no matching text in another `<p>` tag, and no matching text within the same `<p>` tag.

Now, this is what I have thus far for CSS:

```
span.highlight {
    background-color: yellow;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

And what I have for jQuery:

```
function getSelected() {
    var selected = '';

    if (window.getSelection) {
        selected = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.getSelection) {
        selected = document.getSelection();
    } else if (document.selection) {
        selected = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('p').live('mouseup', function() {
        var selected = getSelected();

        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(selected, '<span class="highlight">' + selected + '</span>'));
    });
});
```

Now this works almost. However it will select the first instance of the selected text and highlight that, which isn't what I want, I want it to select the actual selected text. And it has one more problem, once some text is highlighted, if I select more text that includes part of the highlighted text, it won't change it.

I'm wondering if anyone can help with either of these issues? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Sorry, I should have also mentioned that I can't use a plugin. I've taken a look at them and most of them work for my needs quite well, but I can't use them.

Comment: You can solve this problem yourself, or you can use a library from someone else who already has: http://code.google.com/p/rangy/

Comment: Sorry, I just edited my post. I can't use any plugins. But thanks.

Comment: `@Arak`: You can still look at how Tim does it in Rangy and reuse the techniques.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You are right, I could do that. However nobody learns anything from copy and paste. I was hoping to get an explanation behind a way to do what I need to do, so that I can learn from it. I haven't looked at that code specifically, but if it's anything like a couple other plugins, it's over my head anyways.

Comment: I am looking for something along these lines, which will also change already highlighted text if needed. Did you have any success?

Answer (score 2):

I've used: http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html

In the past with good results.

However in your example look at the .replace function.  try .replaceAll instead.

Comment: I appreciate your taking the time to add that. However I can't use plugins, I just edited my post to include that restriction, sorry.

Comment: .replaceAll doesn't work the way I need it to. It works as far as I'm aware by replacing html elements with other html elements. In addition as its name suggests, it replaces all occurrences, not a specific one selected.